# Body lock fullscreen section with slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have a one page website with sections. Using [Swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/) + [body-scroll-lock to lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock) a middle section while the user swipes through the slides.

If user scrolls down the body lock should be active until last slide and vice versa if the user scrolls back to the top of the page.

```
// body lock while going down
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var elementTarget = document.getElementById("the-dashboard");
  if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight) {
    $('html').addClass('no-scroll') // locks 
  }
});
// SWIPER

var leftSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container-left", {
  direction: "vertical",
  mousewheel: {
    invert: true,
    mousewheelReleaseOnEdges: true
  },
  allowTouchMove: false,
  initialSlide: 3
});
var rightSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container-right", {
  direction: "vertical",
  mousewheel: true,
  mousewheelReleaseOnEdges: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination"
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  }
});
rightSwiper.on("reachEnd", function() {
  $('html').removeClass('no-scroll') // unlocks but the first lock still active and locks it again
});
```

**Problem:**
Unable to unlock screen again since user has "passed" the top of the div and not i.e "touched" the top of the div with window top.

**Possible Solution:**
A good way to body lock a section while reaching its top until the Swiper "reachEnd" event is triggered.

**VIEW PEN:** https://codepen.io/rulloliver/pen/LYPyxaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A javascript solution can be found on this pen using mousewheel events: https://codepen.io/kaido24/pen/pozpGwR

Code:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  $target = $("#swipes");
  if (window.scrollY > $target[0].offsetTop && window.scrollY < $target[0].offsetTop + 150) {
     $('html').addClass('no-scroll');
  }
  else {
    $('html').removeClass('no-scroll');
  }
});
var leftSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container-left", {
  direction: "vertical",
 /** mousewheel: {
    invert: true,
    mousewheelReleaseOnEdges: true
  },
**/
  allowTouchMove: false,
  initialSlide: 3
});
var rightSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container-right", {
  direction: "vertical",
 /**   mousewheel: true,
  mousewheelReleaseOnEdges: true, */
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination"
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  }
});
leftSwiper.on("slideNextTransitionStart", function() {
  rightSwiper.slidePrev(500, false);
});
leftSwiper.on("slidePrevTransitionStart", function() {
  rightSwiper.slideNext(500, false);
});
rightSwiper.on("slideNextTransitionStart", function() {
  leftSwiper.slidePrev(500, false);
});
rightSwiper.on("slidePrevTransitionStart", function() {
  leftSwiper.slideNext(500, false);
});
rightSwiper.on("reachEnd", function() {

});
rightSwiper.on("reachBeginning", function() {
});
var waiting = false;

$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
      if ($('html').hasClass('no-scroll')) {
      if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
          if (waiting == false) {
           l = leftSwiper.slideNext();
            if (l == false) {
               $('html').removeClass('no-scroll');
              console.log('top');
              console.log($(window));
            } else {
              waiting = true;
              setTimeout(function () {
                waiting = false;
              },500);
            }
          }
      }
      else {
        if (waiting == false) {
          var r = rightSwiper.slideNext();
          if (r == false) {
            $('html').removeClass('no-scroll');
          } else {
            waiting = true;
            setTimeout(function () {
              waiting = false;
            }, 500);     
          }          
         }
      }
    }
  });
$(document).on('mousewheel', function() {
  $(document).trigger('mousewheel');
});
```

(not by me)